# Check if current page is homepage on Jekyll

Tags: jekyll

There's any way to check if the current page is the homepage?

I want use `h1` tag for the logo image only when the current page is the website base url.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can use [`page.url`](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/variables/#page-variables) to check if the current page is your index page:

```
{% if page.url == "/index.html" %}
   <h1>...</h1>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: I used `{% if page.layout == 'home' %}` but your answer is correct too. Thanks!

Comment: I ended up using if {% if page.url == "/" %} . The rest disn't work for me.

Comment: Looks like in the version of Jekyll I just installed (3.3.1) the page.url for index.md is '/'. For example: 

    `{% if page.url == "/" %}active{% endif %}`

Comment: If **permalink** option is set at Front Matter of the page, *page.url* should be compared to its value. Otherwise, as said above, ```page.url == "/"``` works fine (v3.4.3).

Answer (score 11):

Another option to manage this is adding page IDs to the yml frontmatter

```
{% if page.id == 'index' %}
  content
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 1):

*Along @Christopher's comment* the best is if you test the `page.layout`. Because if permalink is set or in other circumstances the `page.url` can be `"/index.html"`, `"/index"`, or just simply `"/"`. Therefore I think it's more robust:

```
{% if page.layout == 'home' %}
  <h1>logo</h1>
{% else %}
  <h2>smaller logo</h2>
{% endif %}
```